# How to reference the current package for use with importlib.resources?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have an installed package (typically located inside `…/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/my-package`) which contains (among other things) the resources `…/my-package/a.txt` and `…/my-package/b.png`.  I would like to access these resources from `…/my-package/get_my_resources.py` using the following code:

```
txt = importlib.resources.read_text(this_package, 'a.txt')
img = importlib.resources.read_binary(this_package, 'b.png')
```

What should I use for `this_package`?  When I try the relative self-reference `this_package = '.'`, I get the error

```
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.'
```

Answer (score 7):

The embarrassingly simple answer is:

```
this_package = __package__
```

Namely, if you have Python 3.9 or greater,

```
txt = importlib.resources.files(__package__).joinpath('a.txt').read_text()
img = importlib.resources.files(__package__).joinpath('b.png').read_bytes()
```

For details see the [importlib_resources documentation](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html).

*DEPRECATED as of Python 3.11*: The original solution for Python 3.8 and lower was:

```
txt = importlib.resources.read_text(__package__, 'a.txt')
img = importlib.resources.read_binary(__package__, 'b.png')
```